# "Type is not expected" error when serializing unity3d types with precompiled dll generated by protobuf-net

Tags: unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I use protobuf-net to create a static serialization dll for my unity3d project. like this:

```
    RuntimeTypeModel model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

    model.Add(typeof(UnityEngine.Vector3), true).Add("x", "y", "z");
    model.Add(typeof(UnityEngine.Quaternion), true).Add("x", "y", "z", "w");
    model.Add(typeof(MyClass), true);

    model.AllowParseableTypes = true;
    model.AutoAddMissingTypes = false;
    model.AutoCompile = false;
    model.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false;
    model.Compile("GameDataSerializer", "GameDataSerializer.dll");
```

For MyClass I use [ProtoContract] tag and it works properly. However it's not working for unity types like Vector3.

```
        System.Type type = System.Type.GetType("GameDataSerializer, GameDataSerializer");
        TypeModel serializer = (RuntimeTypeModel)type.GetMethod("Create", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Invoke(null, null);
        Vector3 v = new Vector3(1f, 2f, 3f);
        using (FileStream f = new FileStream("testser.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(f, v);
        }
```

I get the following error when I try to save or load a Vector3 object:

```
InvalidOperationException: Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: UnityEngine.Vector3
```

How do I serialize unity3d types with precompiled dll properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem.

Simple answer:

use "new GameDataSerializer()" to construct the runtime serializer object instead of "type.GetMethod("Create", ...)". This works as expected.

Detail explanation:

At first, I tried to construct runtime serializer just like the final solution

`GameDataSerializer serializer = new GameDataSerializer()`

However, unity3d script failed to compile with error "Could not load file or assembly Assembly-CSharp...". So I changed my code to

```
System.Type type = System.Type.GetType("GameDataSerializer, GameDataSerializer");
TypeModel serializer = (RuntimeTypeModel)type.GetMethod("Create", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Invoke(null, null);
```

and everything worked fine, until I met the problem in original question.

The real problem is the precompiled serializer dll is considered a plugin in unity3d.  unity3d compiles plugins before other user scripts(Assembly-csharp). The precompiled serializer dll has a reference to Assembly-csharp because of "MyClass", and that can't be resolved during plugins compilation stage.

So the resolution is to refactor "MyClass" and other serializable data structures to a seperate dll, then compile a serializer dll without a reference to Assembly-csharp. Both the dll can be generated with seperate visual studio project (.net 2.0).

This can be inconvenient if your data structure has strong coupling with other codes and working with seperate projects is annoying. So I tried some other methods:

- put data structure source files into plugins folder, generate serializer dll with editor script
- use a data structure dll, but generate serializer dll with editor script
- decompile the serializer dll to source code

but none of them work. It seems serializer dll generated with editor script always has a reference to Assembly-csharp. And no decompiler is good enough to generate compiling source code. So currently I'm settled with the seperate vs projects solution.